# Django cannot find specified path for FilePathField

Tags: python, django

Trying to use `FilePathField` for my images, but my application returns the following error:

`FileNotFoundError at /api/projects/ | [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'portfolio/img'`

*settings.py*

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

*models.py*

```
class Tech(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    icon    = models.FilePathField(path="portfolio/img")

class Project(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    desc    = models.TextField()
    image   = models.FilePathField(path="portfolio/img")
    tech    = models.ForeignKey(Tech, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

And my current file hierarchy:

```
back
    core
    portfolio
    static
        portfolio
            img
    manage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

u have to make a function that return the file path

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

def images_path():
    return os.path.join(settings.LOCAL_FILE_DIR, 'images')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FilePathField(path=images_path)
```

Comment: Does ``LOCAL_FILE_DIR`` exist as a value of settings or do I need to replace that with the actual file path?

Comment: it is for better use act as const in settings

Answer (score 0):

add at the end settings.py

```
PORTAFOLIO_URL= '/portafolio/'
PORTAFOLIO_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'portafolio')
```

add at the end urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.PORTAFOLIO_URL,document_root=settings.PORTAFOLIO_ROOT)
```